# 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object

Tags: swift2, swift3

I had this code in Swift 2, now it has error in Swift 3:

The error is :

> 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a
>   new object of the same dynamic type

```
extension Date
{

    init(dateString:String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let d = dateStringFormatter.date(from: dateString)!

        // error is here : 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic type
        (self as NSDate).init(timeInterval:0, since:d) }
}
```

Comment: What's with `(self as NSDate)`? Type `Date` has own `init` with same params, why not use it instead of vain type casting? Also `init` is class-level method, not instance-level — that's where your error comes from.

Comment: right, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `super.init(timeInterval:0, since:d)`

Comment: ERROR: 'super' can not be used outside of class members
`code` extension Date {
    init?(jsonDate: String) {
        let prefix = "/Date("
        let suffix = ")/"
if jsonDate.hasPrefix(prefix) && jsonDate.hasSuffix(suffix) {
         let from = jsonDate.characters.index(jsonDate.startIndex, offsetBy: prefix.characters.count)
            let to = jsonDate.characters.index(jsonDate.endIndex, offsetBy: -suffix.characters.count)
            guard let milliseconds = Double(jsonDate[from ..< to]) else {
return nil
}
 super.init(timeIntervalSince1970: milliseconds/1000.0)
 } `code`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below init in Swift 5

```
import Foundation

struct Engine: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String

}

extension Engine {
    static let samples: [Engine] = [
        .init(name: "Merlin", description: "SpaceX Merlin 1 Rocket Engine"),
        .init(name: "Kestrel", description: "SpaceX Kestrel Rocket Engine"),
        .init(name: "Raptor", description: "SpaceX Raptor Rocket Engine"),
        .init(name: "Methox", description: "SpaceX Methox Rocket Engine")
    ]
}
```